# Call to undefined method Carbon\Carbon::getTimestamp()

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

i'm kinda new in Laravel, i'm developing an application, i just went outside and when i get back i suddenly get this error:

> FatalThrowableError in FileSessionHandler.php line 70:
>   Call to undefined method Carbon\Carbon::getTimestamp()

i don't know what to do to solve this problem. Kindly help. Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getTimestamp()` on the Carbon object, so do this if you want to get current timestamp:

```
Carbon\Carbon::now()->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: okay but where will i put that? and everytime i refresh the page and whatever route i want to go i still get the same error

Comment: @RanilJaramillo this will work in any class. I've tried it and this code works perfectly. If you get the error, please show the error message and related code.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I have the same issue. 1) this is an error occurred in the system, not in user code.(see log). 2) This only occurs sometimes, for example, several hours, and then strangely disappear. 3) [Here is my error log](https://gist.github.com/turtlegood/94155e844decb6e0724ded8eb69d4196). This issue almost makes me crazy!!! So I would truly appreciate it if you could help me about this issue! Thank you!!!

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin And 4) I have seen the releated source of laravel kernel. It uses Carbon::now()->getTimestamp() correctly. (So it seems that calling a function on an object will be logged as CLASSNAME::FUNCTIONNAME.)

Answer (score 0):

You probably aren't calling the method correctly. When in a controller, it has to be called through `\Carbon\Carbon::now()->getTimestamp();` insted of `Carbon\Carbon::now()->getTimestamp();`, since it is relative to Laravel's root.

Alternatively, you can also add `use Carbon\Carbon;` before the Controller's initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this question last day,but I now know why,because the php  class DateTime  public method getTimestamp can't be called!
for example like this：

```
    $date = new DateTime();
    echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

you can try that code,if you get error,then you can understand why your laravel error like that!
so in laravel,Carbon extends DateTime,Carbon also can't call getTimestamp()!
Another question,why Datetime::getTimestamp Cant't be called? I now don't know,It may be a php bug?,my php version is 7.0.4! I change another php 7.0.10。It become OK!
hope I can help you!
a new message! I restart my computer,so It is also OK，getTimestamp method can be called right